# Did I understand AdaBoost correctly?

Tags: r, boosting, ensemble-learning, adaboost

My mantra has always been that if you are not able to recreate something you haven't really understood it. In this manner I tried to implement the AdaBoost algorithm of Freund and Schapire

I used one of the original [papers from Schapire](http://rob.schapire.net/papers/explaining-adaboost.pdf) and tried to implement it as close to the original as possible. I used the original pseudocode (as comments) and translated it into R:

```
library(rpart)
library(OneR)

maxdepth <- 1
T <- 100 # number of rounds

# Given: (x_1, y_1),...,(x_m, y_m) where x_i element of X, y_i element of {-1, +1}
myocarde <- read.table("http://freakonometrics.free.fr/myocarde.csv", head = TRUE, sep = ";")
#myocarde <- read.table("data/myocarde.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
y <- (myocarde[ , "PRONO"] == "SURVIE") * 2 - 1
x <- myocarde[ , 1:7]
m <- nrow(x)
data <- data.frame(x, y)

# Initialize: D_1(i) = 1/m for i = 1,...,m
D <- rep(1/m, m)

H <- replicate(T, list())
a <- vector(mode = "numeric", T)
set.seed(123)

# For t = 1,...,T
for(t in 1:T) {
  # Train weak learner using distribution D_t
  # Get weak hypothesis h_t: X -> {-1, +1}
  data_D_t <- data[sample(m, 10*m, replace = TRUE, prob = D), ]
  H[[t]] <- rpart(y ~., data = data_D_t, maxdepth = maxdepth, method = "class")
  # Aim: select h_t with low weighted error: e_t = Pr_i~D_t[h_t(x_i) != y_i]
  h <- predict(H[[t]], x, type = "class")
  e <- sum(h != y) / m
  # Choose a_t = 0.5 * log((1-e) / e)
  a[t] <- 0.5 * log((1-e) / e)
  # Update for i = 1,...,m: D_t+1(i) = (D_t(i) * exp(-a_t * y_i * h_t(x_i))) / Z_t
  # where Z_t is a normalization factor (chosen so that Dt+1 will be a distribution) 
  D <- D * exp(-a[t] * y * as.numeric(h))
  D <- D / sum(D)
}
# Output the final hypothesis: H(x) = sign(sum of a_t * h_t(x) for t=1 to T)
newdata <- x
H_x <- sapply(H, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(predict(x, newdata = newdata, type = "class"))))
H_x <- t(a * t(H_x))
pred <- sign(rowSums(H_x))

#H
#a
eval_model(pred, y)
## 
## Confusion matrix (absolute):
##           Actual
## Prediction -1  1 Sum
##        -1   0  1   1
##        1   29 41  70
##        Sum 29 42  71
## 
## Confusion matrix (relative):
##           Actual
## Prediction   -1    1  Sum
##        -1  0.00 0.01 0.01
##        1   0.41 0.58 0.99
##        Sum 0.41 0.59 1.00
## 
## Accuracy:
## 0.5775 (41/71)
## 
## Error rate:
## 0.4225 (30/71)
## 
## Error rate reduction (vs. base rate):
## -0.0345 (p-value = 0.6436)
```

So far, so good... what I find strange is that when I compare it to AdaBoost packages my results are wanting accuracy wise:

```
library(JOUSBoost)
## JOUSBoost 2.1.0
boost <- adaboost(as.matrix(x), y, tree_depth = maxdepth, n_rounds = T)
pred <- predict(boost, x)
eval_model(pred, y)
## 
## Confusion matrix (absolute):
##           Actual
## Prediction -1  1 Sum
##        -1  29  0  29
##        1    0 42  42
##        Sum 29 42  71
## 
## Confusion matrix (relative):
##           Actual
## Prediction   -1    1  Sum
##        -1  0.41 0.00 0.41
##        1   0.00 0.59 0.59
##        Sum 0.41 0.59 1.00
## 
## Accuracy:
## 1 (71/71)
## 
## Error rate:
## 0 (0/71)
## 
## Error rate reduction (vs. base rate):
## 1 (p-value < 2.2e-16)
```

**My question**
Is there something that I misunderstood concerning the algorithm? Or do the other implementation just use some "tricks" (which?) to tune their results?

Comment: Good work! I think you got everything right. Reading your code quickly the only thing that stuck me is that you are boosting *and bagging*. I don't think we are to sample the distribution $D$, we just update the weights on it. Also, I suspect that the weak learner can be  a bit more flexible. If in the code  you provide we use `data_D_t <- data` directly and we set `control = rpart.control(minbucket=1)` in the `rpart` call (i.e. we can have terminal leaf nodes with a single observation) we get back 100% accuracy.  Wanna check that if this works for you too?

Comment: (I would also suggest using the `boosting` tag too.)

Comment: @usεr11852: Thank you. I use sampling as a workaround because the `weight` argument is - according to the documentation - not yet implemented in `rpart`. I tried `minbucket = 1` but I get an error. Something still seems to be faulty... Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: `rpart::rpart` has a `weights` argument to  my knowledge (e.g. see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/rpart/html/rpart.html)). And `minbucket=1` should not give you an error, it is a totally reasonable argument. Which version of `rpart` are you using?

Comment: And another small point as the paper says "*select $h_t$ with low weighted error*", so instead of `sum(h != y) / m` we probably want something like `sum( (h!=y) * D)`.

Comment: I found another small point that was R-specific regarding casting factors to integers. As mentioned good work, you definitely have the right ideas in your implementation. (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your understanding is fine. There were some minor points in the code that I think they overall accumulated to some quirky results.

1. Bagging. It seems you are *bagging* as well as boosting. That is not part of the original algorithm and is unnecessary here too. I appreciate that you did this because you thought that `rpart` could not take weights so you oversampled to compensate that. (Realistically, a base learner has to use weights in a straightforward manner to be useful for Adaboost.)
2. Not weighting the error. As mentioned in my comment, thee paper says "*select $h_t$ with low weighted error*". So we want something like: `sum( (h!=y) * D)`... I am with you on this, it is far from crystal clear in the paper, the Wikipedia entry on [adaboost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost#Example_algorithm_(Discrete_AdaBoost)) is much more explicit about it.
3. Casting factors to numeric incorrectly. `exp(-a[t] * y * as.numeric(h))` should be `exp(-a[t] * y * as.numeric(as.character( h)))`. It is clear you noticed this later when evaluating the learners, but you forgot to fix this inside the loop. (Even the greats do mistakes!)

I think if you implement these changes you will get an Adaboost code implementation that is really close to the one of the paper. I append a snippet with the fixes below; it leads to 100% accuracy as with the reference implementation in `JOUSBoost`. I think the only methodological point you missed was about the weighting of the error, which is indeed a bit unclear in the paper.

```
...
set.seed(123) 

data_D_t <- data

# For t = 1,...,T
for(t in 1:T) { 
  H[[t]] <- rpart(y ~., data = data_D_t, maxdepth = maxdepth, 
                  method = "class", weights = D)
  h <- predict(H[[t]], x, type = "class")
  e <- sum( (h != y) * D) 
  a[t] <- 0.5 * log((1-e) / e) 
  D <- D * exp(-a[t] * y * as.numeric(as.character(h) ) ) 
  D <- D / sum(D) 
}
# Output the final hypothesis: H(x) = sign(sum of a_t * h_t(x) for t=1 to T)
newdata <- x
H_x <- sapply(H[seq(t)], function(x)
         as.numeric(as.character(predict(x, newdata = newdata, type = "class"))))
H_x <- t(a[seq(t)] * t(H_x))
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Concerning the weights in rpart – the long vignette says that they are not supported yet?!? see p. 23: cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf

Comment: I am glad I could help. Regarding the vignette: I am unclear why it says that... Maybe it is refers to older versions; you might want to contact the maintainer. Setting the `weights` arguments clearly affects the predicted values at the moment (`rpart_4.1-13`).